# How would I get the defined string in string xml file in res in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to get a resource string variables in file string.xml in the res folder in the android directory for libgdx from the core java class files.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant fluff ("so ok" and the begging from your post as part of the review). The resulting sentence doesn not make sense ("I am trying to some resource string"), there seems to be at least a verb missing after "to". Can you update your post with the relevant missing text?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to translate for multiple languages i will tell you that the best way to do it is not using the string.xml file from android.

What i did is. Inside the folder Assets in the android project i create a folder with the name String -> Inside this folder i create the string i will use in my app.

[image: String folder]

Then to load the string i will use I18NBundle. For example:

```
I18NBundle languageStrings = I18NBundle.createBundle(Gdx.files.internal("strings/strings"), locale);
String hello = languageString.get("hello");
```

This will work for Desktop, Android, iOS and GWT. So it better option than using the android res folder.

You can check more of this in the wiki of libgdx [Libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization)

Comment: can you share one of your `strings.properties` with us ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write platform specific code which can be accessed using interfaces: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code